# Guardar dados de formulario dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli

O formulário é criado através de dados obtidos da base de dados MySQL. Gostaria de guardar os dados todos do mesmo ao clicar no submeter.

Problema:

1. Apenas consigo guardar uma linha de cada vez, criando um botao no mesmo `<tr>` e com auxilio de javascript parent('tr');
2. Ao guardar o valor de cada uma das caixas de texto geradas
   dinamicamente, não consigo gravar o formulário por completo, ou seja, aquilo que pretendo.

### Código PHP do Formulário

```
<?php
include('conetar.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `opcoes` WHERE `tipo` = 1 ;");


echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'id='datatables-example'>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Antes da Instalação do Sistema Operativo</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Verificação</b></td>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' value=".$row['IDOpcao']."></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Opcao'] . "</td>";
echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'>  <input type='checkbox' name='Validacao'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' class='form-control' value='". $row['IDOpcao'] . "'>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>




<br>

<?php
include('conetar.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `opcoes` WHERE `tipo` = 2 ;");

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'id='datatables-example'>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Instalação e Configuração (Base)</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Versão Antiga</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Versão Nova</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Verificação Prévia</b></td>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> <input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' value=".$row['IDOpcao']."></td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Opcao'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>  <input type='text' name='VersaoAntiga' id= 'VersaoAntiga-".$row['IDOpcao']."' class='form-control versao_antiga'></td>"; 
echo "<td>  <input type='text' id='VersaoNova-".$row['IDOpcao']."' name='VersaoNova' class='form-control' disabled='true'></td>";
echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name= 'VerificacaoPrevia'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' class='form-control' value='". $row['IDOpcao'] . "'>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
<!--Script para copiar para um ficheiro-->

<script>

$(document).ready(function(e){
$(".versao_antiga").on('input', function(e) {
var elemento = $(this);
var idElemento = elemento.attr("id").split('-')[1];

$("#VersaoNova-" + idElemento).prop('disabled', elemento.val().length == 0);
});
});
</script>
<br>
<!--Script para copiar para um ficheiro-->

<?php
include('conetar.php');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `opcoes` WHERE `tipo` = 3 ;");

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'id='datatables-example'>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Instalação e Configuração (Complementar)</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Versão Antiga</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Versão Nova</b></td>
<td class='pure-table'><b>Verificação Prévia</b></td>


</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

echo "<tbody data-link='row' class='rowlink'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>   <input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' value=".$row['IDOpcao']."></td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['Opcao'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>  <input type='text' name='VersaoAntiga' id= 'VersaoAntiga-".$row['IDOpcao']."' class='form-control versao_antiga'></td>"; 
echo "<td>  <input type='text' id='VersaoNova-".$row['IDOpcao']."' name='VersaoNova' class='form-control' disabled='true'></td>";
echo "<td  style='text-align:center;'><input type='checkbox' name= 'VerificacaoPrevia' ></td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";    
echo "<input type='hidden' name='IDOpcao' class='form-control' value='". $row['IDOpcao'] . "'>";
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

### Imagem de Formulário

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Amigo primeiramente tente trabalhar com OO + PDO. Crie uma classe DAO e escreva lá o seu CRUD e terá melhor controle e resultado... Eu no seu caso criaria dois métodos inserir exemplo:

```
 public function cadastrar(Ficha $ficha1)
{

    $this->ficha = $ficha1;


    //EXTRAINDO OBJETO PARA VARIAVEL
    $nome = $this->ficha->getUser();
    $professor = $this->ficha->getProfessorAvaliado();
    $turma = $this->ficha->getTurma();
    $campus = $this->ficha->getCampus();
    $disciplina = $this->ficha->getDisciplina();
    $nivel = $this->ficha->getNivel();
    $questa1 = $this->ficha->getQ1();
    $questa2 = $this->ficha->getQ2();
    $questa3 = $this->ficha->getQ3();
    $questa4 = $this->ficha->getQ4();
    $questa5 = $this->ficha->getQ5();
    $questa6 = $this->ficha->getQ6();
    $parecer = $this->ficha->getParecer();




    //--------------------------------------
    try{

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ficha(user,professorAvaliado,turma,campus,disciplina,nivel,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,parecer) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$nome);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$professor);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$turma);
        $stmt->bindParam(4,$campus);
        $stmt->bindParam(5,$disciplina);
        $stmt->bindParam(6,$nivel);
        $stmt->bindParam(7,$questa1);
        $stmt->bindParam(8,$questa2);
        $stmt->bindParam(9,$questa3);
        $stmt->bindParam(10,$questa4);
        $stmt->bindParam(11,$questa5);
        $stmt->bindParam(12,$questa6);
        $stmt->bindParam(13,$parecer);

        $resultado = $stmt->execute();

        if ($resultado){
            echo "dados inseridos com sucesso";
        }


    }  catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Para saber mais sobre relacionamentos NxN http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: Eu estou a criar um simples formulário, creio que não faça sentido usar uma framwork MVC para este caso.Eu consigo gravar se for linha a linha usando jquery com `parent('tr')`, mas, eu gostaria de guardar tudo ao fazer submite.

Comment: @djva Claro que faz sentido usar PDO... e não digo de Framework MVC. PDO não é um FrameWork MVC ele só substitui o MSQLI (que esta depreciando). A metodologia MVC OO etc lhe ajuda justamente com isso, nas resoluções de problemas... É recomendavel que qualquer sistema desde que um simples formulário siga os padrões de OO com classes Bean, DAO, etc... Há quanto tempo trabalha com PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

Para guardar o formulário completo, você pode utilizar o método POST do HTML para enviar os dados do formulário para o PHP.

Para isso, basta adicionar um elemento form no seu código HTML e incluir todos os elementos de input (caixas de texto, checkboxes, etc) dentro dele. Em seguida, adicione um botão de submit (botão para enviar o formulário) com o atributo type="submit".

Veja um exemplo de como ficaria o código:

```
<form method="post" action="processar_formulario.php">
  <!-- Inclua todos os elementos de input aqui -->
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar formulário">
</form>
```

O atributo action especifica para qual página o formulário deve ser enviado, e o atributo method especifica qual método HTTP (POST ou GET) deve ser utilizado para enviar os dados. No exemplo acima, utilizamos o método POST.

No arquivo PHP que irá processar o formulário (no caso, "processar_formulario.php"), você pode acessar os dados enviados pelo formulário utilizando o array superglobal $_POST. Por exemplo, para acessar o valor de uma caixa de texto com o nome "nome", basta utilizar $_POST['nome'].

Você pode então usar esses dados para inserir os valores na tabela MySQL utilizando uma query INSERT. Por exemplo:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (nome, email) VALUES ('$nome', '$email')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Lembre-se de validar os dados do formulário antes de inserir na base de dados, para garantir que os dados inseridos são válidos e não podem ser usados para ataques como SQL injection.